# UNION or JOIN 4 tables that have inner join each one

Tags: mysql, join, union

I need to know if can I JOIN (FULL or LEFT) or UNION (ALL) these tables I have. The think is I need to show all user with membership in a list, but I have 5 tables of different users in total and each one have INNER JOIN with another tables to show instead of ID the name of that ID.

HERE I show you two tables I need to JOIN or UNION.

```
$query = "SELECT M.id_med, M.nombres, M.apellidos, M.especialidad, M.subespecialidad, M.foto, M.visto,
                    CM.nombre_categoria, EM.nombre_especialidad
                    FROM MEDICOS M
                    INNER JOIN PAISES P ON M.pais = P.id
                    INNER JOIN DEPARTAMENTOS D ON M.departamento = D.id
                    INNER JOIN MUNICIPIOS N ON M.municipio = N.id
                    INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS_MEDICAS CM ON M.especialidad = CM.id_categoria
                    INNER JOIN ESPECIALIDAD_MED EM ON M.subespecialidad = EM.id_especialidad
                    WHERE CONCAT(',', (pertenece), ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', 5, ',%') AND foto != '/images/nopic.jpg' AND estado = 'activado'
                    AND status = 'vivo' AND hot != '0' AND imag != '0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20

                    FULL JOIN // I tried with UNION ALL, LEFT JOIN but without success

                    SELECT o.id_odont, o.nombres, o.apellidos, o.especialidad, o.subespecialidad, o.foto, o.visto,
                    CO.nombre_categoria, EO.nombre_especialidad
                    FROM ODONTOLOGOS O
                    INNER JOIN PAISES P ON O.pais = P.id
                    INNER JOIN DEPARTAMENTOS D ON O.departamento = D.id
                    INNER JOIN MUNICIPIOS N ON O.municipio = N.id
                    INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS_ODONTO CO ON O.especialidad = CO.id_categoria
                    INNER JOIN ESPECIALIDAD_ODONTO EO ON O.subespecialidad = EO.id_especialidad
                    WHERE CONCAT(',', (pertenece), ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', 5, ',%') AND foto != '/images/nopic.jpg' AND estado = 'activado'
                    AND status = 'vivo' AND hot != '0' AND imag != '0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20
                    ";
```

Hope that you can help me with this. 
I only show two of 4 tables (MEDICOS, ODONTOLOGOS, NEGOCIOS, PSICOLOGOS) that I need to join or union.

Comment: If the four tables are of compatible structures, you can `UNION` them together and then do the required `JOIN` operations.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes in UNION need to have the same numbers of row in each SELECT and the same type too, but I don't know if I need UNION first the four tables and then make the INNER JOINS or if like I already have is good and only make the UNION

Comment: Comenting in spanish because of cellphone dictionary, sorry. Necesitas 3 union que agrupen 4 conjuntos de datos. Cada conjunto de datos contendría una select con joins para sus datos específicos. Recuerda que con unions todas las selects deben devolver la misma cantidad de columnas

Comment: Change the full join and use a union. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp